# IOS segue on IF condition won't work

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, if-statement, segue

Trying to make this segue only run if the username and password are entered correctly.

but even if I enter them incorrectly it displays the message and still runs the segue?  how do I fix this?

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    if (username.text == "username" && password.text == "password") {
        print("you may login")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "admin") as! admin
        viewController.msgtxt = username.text!
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if (username.text != "username" && password.text != "password"){ 
        loginMsg.text = "incorrect username and/or password"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well, you probably don't need the second `if (username.text != "username" && password.text != "password")` condition, if it fails the first, then this branch must be true by default

Comment: Probably in storyboard you have created segue from Button to the `viewcontroller`, so simply remove that one and create another one from Source viewController to destination ViewController.

Comment: im aware of that, but it is not the issue. 

i am going to make it depend on what is entered eventually i.e for if "username" is entered take them to a certain page and if "admin" is entered take them to another page. (its for a uni task) but atm it runs the segue no matter what regardless of the IF condition

Comment: @NiravD thanks Im new to this and didnt realise a segue can be made from view to view instead of button  thanks

Comment: @james.d_12 Welcome mate :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Even worse, in this code if one is right and the other not nothing happens. For OP: negating `A &&B` is not `!A && !B`, it is `!A || !B`

Comment: Just wanna add, pass your data inside the prepareForSegue. Also, in the future, you would want to use R.Swift library to make your codes even cleaner and avoid crash/error by typos. :)